# Is it possible to have one ViewModel in another ViewModel in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where a supplier can have multiple addresses. So I have created a `CommunicationDetailsViewModel` like below:

```
public class CommunicationDetailsViewModel
{
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Country { get; set; }

    public List<State> State { get; set; }

    public List<City> City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32), Required(ErrorMessage ="Address is required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
```

}

I have another `ViewModel` called `SuppllierInformationViewModel` like below:

```
public class SupplierInformationViewModel
{
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Organization name cannot be greater than 50 characters"), Required(ErrorMessage ="Organization name is required")]
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public List<CommunicationDetailsViewModel> CommunicationDetailsViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

I created this `ViewModel` because Supplier can have multiple addresses in. So created a collection of `CommunicationDetailsViewModel`. And going further the Supplier entity is going to have other information like Bank Information, Tax Information, etc. So I thought of creating a `ViewModel` for each of these and one `SupplierInformationViewModel` to hold all these other `ViewModels`.  Can we create `ViewModel` of `ViewModels`?

In the view, I have to bind these multiple addresses. Below is my view:

```
@model WebAPI.ViewModels.SupplierInformationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Supplier Information";
}

<h4>Supplier Details</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SupplierInformation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Organization name")
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.OrganizationName).Name("OrganizationName").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Organization Name" })
        </div>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Country")
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("CountryId").DataTextField("CountryName").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(Model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].Country))
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("State")
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("StateId").DataTextField("StateName").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(Model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].State))
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("City")
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("CityId").DataTextField("CityName").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(Model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].City))
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Address")
                @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].Address).Name("Address").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Address", @maxlength = "32" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Building name")
                @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => Model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].BuildingName).Name("BuildingName").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Address", @maxlength = "32" })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnSave").Content("Save").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit", @class = "k-button k-primary" })
}
```

Now when I post back to the action, I do get `OrganizationName` in `SupplierInformationViewmodel` but `CommunicationDetailsViewModel` as null.
Why is that? Does it have anything to do with the naming conventions? If so, how can I handle that?
Any help appreciated.

My action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(SupplierInformationViewModel supplierInformationViewModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You are creating `name` attributes that have no relationship to you model. Refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand the relationship (e.g it would be `CommunicationDetailsViewModel[0].CountryId` etc

Comment: Use the strong typed `Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].CountryId`, ...` so that the correct name attributes are generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use strongly-typed `DropDownListFor()` to bind with nested viewmodel like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].CountryId)
              .DataTextField("CountryName")
              .DataValueField("Id")
              .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => 
                  read.Action("GetCountry", "ControllerName")
               ))
 )
```

When using `DropDownListFor()`, then `Name("CountryId")` becomes unnecessary.

Also you may try to add parameterless constructor which assigns new instance of `List<CommunicationDetailsViewModel>`:

```
public class SupplierInformationViewModel
{
    public SupplierInformationViewModel()
    {
        this.CommunicationDetailsViewModel = new List<CommunicationDetailsViewModel>();
    }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Organization name cannot be greater than 50 characters"), Required(ErrorMessage ="Organization name is required")]
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public List<CommunicationDetailsViewModel> CommunicationDetailsViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. But my scenario is now getting complicated for me. I want to generate controls dynamically and post their values. I would better create separate question for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use indexing and strongly-typed `DropDownListFor()`, in order to generate the correct name attributes and point to the items in your loop:

```
Model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].CountryId
```

Like this:

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.CommunicationDetailsViewModel[i].CountryId)
```